# Netbeans no compila los cambios que realizo a mi proyecto en java

Tags: java, netbeans, compilar

Tengo instalado Netbeans 19 y el jdk 17 , cuando escribo un programa y lo corro lo ejecuta correctamente, pero cuando realizo cualquier cambio y lo vuelvo a ejecutar no se refleja ningún cambio

[image: He tomado una captura del programa ejecutando un cambio]

Comment: tools > options, yo creo que lo más probable es que no tengas activada la opción compile on save